# using different RecyclerView item layout when working with real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to populate a recyclerview with different data (and adopts a different layout) after a item in the recyclerview is clicked. The data used to populate the recyclerview is from a firebase real time database. When an item is clicked, the recyclerview is supposed to show the children of node selected. Instead of starting a new activity and inflating an whole new layout. I want to try changing one part of a single layout. I figure there may be a performance benefit with respect to render, memory, and battery performance (and also have smaller apk because there are less files to include). I'm aware that I will need to profile the code and compare it to the case where I have multiple activities, but first I would like to get the code to move up and down the database. My MainFragment includes a listener that is called in the Adapter class for the recyclerview (Shown below).

```
@Override
public void setItemLayoutResuorce(String key) {
    Log.i("Hilarity", "SILR");
    mMessagesDatabaseReference = mMessagesDatabaseReference.child(key);
    Log.i("Hilarity", mMessagesDatabaseReference.getKey());
    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (mMessagesDatabaseReference.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.languages))) {
                String langauge = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                languages.add(langauge);
                jokeAdapter.notifyItemInserted(languages.size() - 1);
                jokeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i("Hilarity", "languages add");
            } else {
                Log.i("Hilarity", "joke added");
                Joke joke = dataSnapshot.getValue(Joke.class);
                jokes.add(joke);
                jokeAdapter.notifyItemInserted(jokes.size() - 1);
                jokeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    jokeAdapter = new JokeAdapter(getActivity(), jokes, languages, this, true);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(jokeAdapter);
```

It's called in Adapter.ViewHolder.onClick() (shown below)

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        if (view instanceof TextView) {
            showJokes = true;
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            rvc.setItemLayoutResuorce(textView.getText().toString());
        }
    }
```

The fatal error comes when I click a recycler view item and the recyclerview needs to be repopulated with data, but there is no data (yet), I get an index out of bounds exception in Adapter.onBindViewHolder. It's like the childEventListener, doesn't get reset even though it gets reinstaniated in the listener I've created (it was originally created in MainFragment.onCreate()).

How can I get the database to send the new data after a button is clicked (everything else seems to work, a new layout resource is used all I need is data to populate the recyclerview)? Do you think writing this part of the code in C++ and manually deleting (and then creating) references to the DatabaseReference and ChildEventListener objects would work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you having a deal with updating your RecyclerView content directly from datasource(Firebase in your case) in background thread.

The best practice is to collect all the data you need to display in your RecyclerView in background thread, save it to local copy(local ArrayList or Map, depends on your data structure) on UI thread, and only after request  content update from adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged()` or different update method.

Also in your code I found redundant calls:

```java
jokeAdapter.notifyItemInserted(jokes.size() - 1);
jokeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

There is no need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` right after calling `notifyItemInserted()`, as the first update should update all items in adapter from specified position till last one. An additional call of `notifyDataSetChanged` just repeats an update, but for all items.